# AmazonDynamoDBClent instantiation latency

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating AWS Lambda function in Java to access DynamoDB table. I noticed that AmazonDynamoDBClent instantiation takes several seconds sometimes - normally after I didn't call my lambda function for a while.

Means normally when I send several requests to my Lambda in a row I wait about 10 seconds for the first response and less than second for any subsequent calls. It is not a rule though - from time to time some request in the middle is slow too.

I tried several AmazonDynamoDBClent with or without parameters and didn't see any difference.

Any tip how to get rid of this latency? Anything to configure with DynamoDB? Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing a NO-OP periodically will help keep your Lambda function warm. [Measurements](https://blog.newrelic.com/2017/01/11/aws-lambda-cold-start-optimization/) performed by newrelic suggest that invoking functions at intervals between 1 and 10 minutes is enough to avoid frequent cold starts. [New containers may be used](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) even though your function is warm in response to load.

Other places to look for latency improvements include the CPU/memory footprint of your Lambda function, the size of your executable package, the runtime and other innocuous network requests.

Interactions on the [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=181348) and the newrelic article above suggest that increasing the CPU/memory size of Lambda function containers is another good way to control and reduce latency.

Are you depending on the whole SDK or just the DynamoDB SDK when you build your zip/jar? Weed out unneeded dependencies for the smallest package possible. Also, backporting code aggressively is another way to reduce package size if all you need from a library is a single function.

If your application allows it, you may experience lower latency with the Python and NodeJS runtimes.

Finally, are you trying to read configuration for your lambda from other services like a file in S3, you can take the following steps to reduce setup time in your lambda function:

1. Bake the configuration into the lambda function if it changes very infrequently or you have a finite and small set of combinations to handle
2. Refactor your handler to read more configuration from the InputStream payload
3. Manage configuration using Lambda environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! Yes, switching to NodeJS together with more frequent calls to lambda helped a lot. I'll try to play with CPU/memory to see whether it makes any significant difference.